# Dealing with pagination in database with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I'm trying to get all data from a custom API (flask with PostgresSQL database) using '$http' service in my controller but the api and database is constructed with pagination which means that if I wan't to access data a need to create services like this:

```
/*FIRST PAGE*/     
$http.get("/api/test", testData)
                .success(...)
/*SECOND PAGE*/
$http.get("/api/test?page=2", testData)
                .success(...)
```

This is obviously not good solution but it works ! So could you guide me how to deal with this situation better ? because i know that this api contains over 1 thousand pages...

Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

This is decribed in the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Angular's `$http` service supports `config` param (second param of `.get`) which supports `params` parameter and do all the concatentaion with proper encoding etc etc for you.

> `params – {Object.<string|Object>}` – Map of strings or objects which
>   will be serialized with the `paramSerializer` and appended as GET
>   parameters.

So you can do

```
  angular
    .module('xxx')
    .factory('getPagedData', function ($http) {
      return function(page) {
        return $http.get("/api/test", { params: { page: page } });
      }
    });
```

And use it like this:

```
function someController(getPagedData) {
  getPagedData(2).then(...); // will do GET /api/test?page=2
}
```

Also note, the `.success` method is [deprecated](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.10/docs/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice). It is even removed in Angular 1.6. Use `.then` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

While this seems like a logical solution...

```
/* SERVICE */
var baseUrl = "/api/test";

MyService.getTests = function(page, testData) {
  var pageParams = "";
  if (page > 1) {
    pageParams = "?page="+page;
  }
  return $http.get(baseUrl+pageParams, testData).success().error();
}
```

...`GET` requests don't allow you to send any data. I'm not sure how you plan to send `testData` to a `$http.get` request. The second parameter of a `GET` request is the config object, which makes your service much simpler.

```
var baseUrl = "/api/test";
MyService.getTests = function(page, testData) {
  return $http.get(baseUrl, {params: {page: page})  //becomes /api/test?page=1
  .success()
  .error();
}
```

Comment: Don't ever do this. Angulars' `$http` service supports `config` param (second param of `.get`) which supports `params` parameter and do all the concatentaion with proper encoding etc etc for you.

Comment: You should submit this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just pass a variable every time you want to page to the next data set. So you would have:

```
$http.get("/api/test?page="+ pageNum, testData).success(..)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: But what if I want to know how much records I have in my whole data set ? Can I join data from all my gets to one array ? Is this a "good pratice" solution ?

Comment: Does the API have a call to get all records?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a service that uses promises to access the data and break apart the data the way you want:

```
      function getTestData(testData) {

        return $http.get("/api/test", testData)
            .then(function(response){ //Promise is successful create an object to store the data
            }, handleError);

        function testError(response){//Handle any errors if the promise fails
            return response;
        }
    }
```